# Visual Studio Cordova template/AngularJSTodo example project debug issue

Tags: cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

Fresh install of Visual studio 2013 update 4 and Cordova toolset. Trying to start debug of basic cordova template or AngularJsTodo example project ends in breaking at end of js files. Look at link. I can click continues and get to Chrome with everything seeming ok, BUT Dom Explorer is empty at VS2013. Also no breakpoints will be hit.

I had this example project working a week ago with no problems. Whats going on here?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bU8B.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug that appeared since a recent update to Chrome, and it is being worked on. You can run your app on Ripple by hitting F5 through the debugger breaks (hardly satisfactory), or Ctrl+F5 to start your app without debugging in Ripple. To debug, the better option is to run on an emulator. The VS Emulator for Android on VS 2015 Preview has been working well for me. In VS 2013, GenyMotion is probably the best option for Android.

Comment: Thank you. I think I didn't update Chrome version before problem started, BUT best news is that it is a bug. Just could not find anyone else with same problems..

Comment: Oh yes, there are other of us having the same, annoying problem. Makes it almost impossible to do any debugging.