# VS 2015 CTP 6, Cordova Ripple debugging

Tags: visual-studio-cordova, visual-studio-2015

Having a problem debugging Android and IOS using Ripple.  I am using the Blank App(Apache Cordova) project with no changes.

**Problem:**
The first time I build the project and test with Ripple, Chrome and Ripple work correctly.  Subsequent builds causes JavaScript breaks that block the app from running. When I F5 thru the breaks, the Ripple UI and App appear in Chrome.

**Steps To Repeat:**

- Open my blank Cordova app.
- Select Debug > Android > Ripple - Nexus 7.
- Build the app by clicking on the green build button. **App runs fine.**
- Close the browser and stop debugging
- Build the app again by clicking on the green build button. App does not appear in Chrome.
- JavaScript highlighted in yellow appears in the IDE.
- Click F5 to continue through breaks. Ripple and App appears in Chrome when all breaks have been viewed.

[image: Highlighted JavaScript]

**Fix:**

None.

I can Continue (F5) the scripts until the app and Ripple appears in Chrome. Closing the project and reopening it will allow the app to run properly, but the problems repeat when I debug the project after the 1st attempt.

Comment: I experience this issue intermittently as well - its very frustrating - especially if you have quite a bit of javascript files in your solution. Sometimes cleaning the solution helps - but if all else fails i usually just "Start Without debugging" or Ctrl + F5 - and then debug in the browser rather than Visual Studio..

Comment: MarkP,  Thanks for the feedback.  It's good to hear that someone else is experiencing the same or similar problem.  "Frustrating" is an understatement.  I originally thought the problem was with Chrome and tried the following versions, but it did not fix the problem: - 39.0.2171.65 - 40.0.2214.115 - 41.0.2272.76 -42.0.2311.22

Comment: This issue is also experienced by other users running CTP3 of Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova:
[Visual Studio 2013 Update 4 and Apache Cordova CTP3 Breaking/Stopping on Javascript lines with no breakpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28376223/visual-studio-2013-update-4-and-apache-cordova-ctp3-breaking-stopping-on-javascr), 
[Visual Studio Cordova template/AngularJSTodo example project debug issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188984/visual-studio-cordova-template-angularjstodo-example-project-debug-issue)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that will be fixed in the next update.  See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188984/visual-studio-cordova-template-angularjstodo-example-project-debug-issue) for a full explanation and suggested workaround.